# Android Browser 6.0.1 Marshmallow - JQuery masked plugin in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

Android browsers(6.0.1) date masked input values displaying in reverse order

Actual date format `(mm/dd/yyyy)` eg: `10/02/2016`

But when i enter the above value it is displaying `16/10/2200`

[Link to reproduce on their official library](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: replace type="text" by  type="tel"  fixed this issue.